# ActiveRecord PSQL sort by most recent created_at of has_many association + pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pagination, kaminari

As from the title, I want to show a list of users- sorted by the most recent creation of a `has_many` association.

```
User
  has_many :interactions
```

I need to be able to display a table with the Users- sorted by their last `interaction` date, the table should display the total count of interactions as well (not using `counter_cache` in the DB), and also include pagination.

The previous (not working) scope we've been using is along the lines of `User.with_a_bunch_of_scopes.includes(:interactions).order("interactions.created_at DESC")`
I've deleted most of the attempts, but I've tried using `MAX(interactions.created_at)` and grouping by various other attributes, but to no avail.

The pagination is the hard part here- It seems, unless I'm messing something up, that using `:includes` / `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is properly limiting to only one user per interaction, however, it seems that is scoping by other interactions. I'm using the Kaminari gem, but am able to replicate the problems using `limit` and `offset`

For example:

```
Interaction Users sorted_by interactions.created_at
-------------------------
User 1
User 1
User 2
User 3
User 2
User 2
User 4
User 1
User 4
User 3
User 5
```

Gives us:

```
Page # per 4
Page 1 - [1, 2, 3, 4]
Page 2 - [2, 4, 1, 3]
Page 3 - [4, 3, 5]
```

Whereas we expect it to be:

```
Page # per 4
Page 1 - [1, 2, 3, 4]
Page 2 - [5]
```

It properly only includes each user only once, however, it's including users on pages when they were already included on previous pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Been coming back to this every now and then trying to solve it for a while, and can never get it to return as expected.

Comment: Could you please post your query? Also, are you storing the interactions count per user in the database (for example, using `counter_cache`) or just generating it dynamically (e.g. `user.interactions.size`)?

Comment: @mmichael - Edited the OP with those changes. Dynamic counts (Although worth sacrificing the total count if we can get the sort order working) and posted the base query I'm using. I've tried loads of others, but nothing has worked so I've deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an array of user objects, and since you're dynamically generating the interactions count for each user, you could do this (along with pagination) by mapping `as_json` for each unique user of all sorted interactions:

```
User.includes(:interactions).order('interactions.created_at desc').uniq.page(params[:page]).per(4).map(&:as_json)
```

To make `map(&:as_json)` work you'll need to override the `as_json` method in the User model and include a method for calculating the interactions count. For example:

```
def as_json(_opts={})
  super(_opts.merge({
    methods: [ :interactions_count ]
  }))
end

def interactions_count
  interactions.size
end
```

This should give you an array of user objects including their interactions count. If you're looking for just the user ids, you could just do:

```
User.includes(:interactions).order('interactions.created_at desc').uniq.page(params[:page]).per(4).pluck(:id)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected either. The `uniq` is causing blank spots on pages where duplicates could lie instead of being filled in from following pages. So if page 1 was requesting 10, it might only return 5 if those 5 people had been a part of the 10 most recent interactions.